# Upgrade to SDL Web 8

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, 2011-sp1, upgrade

We have a SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 installation and are in the process of upgrading to SDL Web 8. Can we directly upgrade 2011sp1 to Web8 or do we need to do this incrementally (2011sp1 to 2013sp1 and then 2013sp1 to web8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C) the answer to your question is specifically addressed:

> SDL Web supports only a specific set of upgrade paths to upgrade to SDL Web 8.
>
> You can upgrade to the current version of SDL Web (formerly called SDL Tridion) from the following versions:
>
> - SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 (Hotfix Rollup 1)
> - SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2 (Hotfix Rollup 2)
>
> You can also upgrade the add-on products compatible with these versions. For example, User Interface Update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 is compatible with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2.

Comment: Thanks Bart. I had already read the documentation, however wasn't sure since we don't have 2011 SP1 HR#2 installed. So I think the easier upgrade path would be to first install HR#2 and then upgrade to Web 8.